# JavaScript: Why backslash placed at the end of the string breaks the JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, escaping

But backslash placed anywhere else doesn't breaks the script.

eg: `abcd\` will break the script,
while `a\bcd` will not break the script.

Comment: `\\` is escape sequences it must be followed by a character, A good read https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the string backslash is an escape symbol. When you write:

```
"abcd\"
```

you string literal is never finished, for the quotes are escaped. You need to write:

```
"abcd\\"
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you "escaped" quotes, that is, if you make string like this

```
var a = "abcd\"
```

it will escape that quote and practically leave your string unclosed, which breaks the script.

You could do double backslash in order to put the backslash on the end if that is what you wanted.

```
var a = "abcd\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

because javascript escapes with backslash, meaning that it will try to escape the next character, but since there is none, its fails.
In order to output a literal backslash, escape it, so your output should be abcd\\